# How to delete an input in a text file?

Tags: python

I'm learning python right now. I want to ask if is there a way to input a data , locate the data in a text file and remove it?

For instance, in my text file

`PSP0101
PMF0101
PHP0101`

But I want to delete only PMF0101. So it will become like this

`PSP0101
PHP0101`

Thank youu

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use:

```
import re
# read the file contents
the_file = open('some_file.txt', 'r')
data = the_file.read()
the_file.close()

# find, replace, and write to file
to_remove = "PMF0101"
data = re.sub(r"{}\s+".format(re.escape(to_remove)), "", data)
the_file = open('some_file.txt', 'w')
the_file.write(data)
the_file.close()
```

Comment: do you mind if i ask how would you loop this whole thing?

Comment: @S.Iskandr I couldn't understand what you meant by ***loop this whole thing***

Comment: well, i meant that for instance I asked for the input at the variable to_remove so how do i loop it so it can end with a condition?